# Email user when file is uploaded to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-s3, automation, mailchimp

Is there a way to automatically email a user when a certain file is uploaded to S3? We have a spreadsheet with contact information as well as a file name associated with that person. Once a person's file is uploaded, is there a way to send that user an automated email?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use AWS API Gateway to create an endpoint that accepts the file to upload and then, using AWS Lambda, upload it to S3 and trigger an event to send the email using mailchimp or AWS SES. Check this: https://codehabitude.com/2016/04/05/forms-to-emails-using-aws-lambda-api-gateway/

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Configure an **Amazon S3 event** to trigger a Lambda function when a file is uploaded
- Code the **AWS Lambda function** to lookup who should receive the notification and then send the message via **Amazon SES** (Simple Email Service)